# Change the Display name at DM API, does not affect A360 files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I'm trying to rename a file from A360 using the Data Management API. I did that by changing the name both at Data displaName label and the Included version. But the name does not change for this same file at A360.

Does anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

We're now ensuring only `name` attribute is actually used (both via UI and API), so the `displayName` should not be used.